# How to get rid of this "edge" in .NET Winforms app?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, highdpi

I have a .NET Winforms app that is showing odd edges that I can't get rid of.  The edges only appear when <dpiAware> is set to true in app.manifest.  I'm on Windows 10 with a high-DPI screen.  See the picture below.  Any ideas?

[image: Mystery Edges]

Comment: When what is set to true in app.manifest?

Comment: When <dpiAware> is true - I edited the question to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether you use next settings, in:

**app.config** file:

`<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
    <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
  </System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>`

**Main()** of you application, you set these:

`Application.EnableVisualStyles();
 Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);`

**Designer file** of you form, the properties of the form:

`this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
 this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;`

The problem, you described above, can be reproducible when you use 2 monitors with different dpi scale. Your main monitor uses 200% and your secondary 100%. To fix it you can change the "primary" monitor
[setting to change the main monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sohss.png)

Comment: Thanks - I think you hit the nail on the head with having 2 monitors at different dpi scale.  When I remove one monitor, the artifacts are gone.